# Resistive ribbon sensor multiple readings

Tags: voltage-divider, potentiometer

I created a resistive ribbon sensor using a resistive strip as follows:

[image]

When making contact between A0 and the resistive ribbon (e.g. at the location of the red circle) using a bridge, I can successfully read out the location of this contact on the resistive ribbon strip.

So this all works, but now I want to detect the location of multiple of these bridges (more than 2) on the same resistive strip. For this I use multiple of these bridges. So my Idea is that every "bridge" makes contact with the same resistive strip and a unique analog pin. Essential here is that I want to use the same resisitve strip if possible. I'm not sure how to do this but this is probably not correct I guess?

[image]

I don't need all analog readings at the same time, so maybe some kind of multiplexing strategy over time could work as well?

EDIT:
My problem can indeed be seen as a potentiometer with multiple wipers (the red circles in my drawing). Since I do not only want to measure the voltage on the analog input but also want to extract the resistance (which represents the position of the "bridge"), I need to add a fixed resistor (R1) in the design (as seen in the first figure). What still remains unclear to me is how to wire everything up when I have multiple wipers on the same resistive strip (and thus multiple analog pins)? So how can I measure the locations of multiple wipers using a known (fixed) resistor?

Comment: You have ground and A0 shown incorrectly in your diagrams.

Comment: The first schematic seems to work correctly though?

Comment: Then you have drawn it incorrectly.

Comment: I updated the first figures to what I think should be correct. Altough I also updated the second one, I'm pretty sure this is incorrect. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Why is analog 0 connected to analog 2?

Comment: I have no idea of how else I can do this. Not sure if its even possible to do this by sharing the same resistive ribbon? Hence my question.

Comment: You are showing crappy pictures that make no sense electrically and you expect anyone looking at them to understand what you are trying to do. You must find a way of explaining yourself to get this answered.

Comment: I tried to explain my problem better. Let me know if it is still unclear... 
So in the first example I create this bridge at the location of the red circle and I can detect the position of this bridge. Hope this is correct now? Next thing is that I want to detect the position of multiple "bridges" every bridge can have its own analog pin but they should share the same resistive ribbon strip.

Comment: You should remove the horizontal line above R1 in your drawings - that appears to be shorting all the ADC inputs, and the top of R1, together.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I updated the drawing but I'm not sure where to place R2 and R3 (the known resistors), so I can calculate the resistance of the variable resistor using these fixed resistors for every analog input?

Answer (score 1):

OK I see what you mean now. Yes this can work providing the bridge draws very little current. If it does draw current it will upset the readings seen by the other analogue inputs. On the face of it the analogue inputs should take zero current but this is not true. If they are the inputs to an ADC it is likely that the current taken has several tens of micro amps of noise. Some ADCs are better than others of course - the devil is in the detail.

Given this, I would consider placing op-amp unity gain buffers between ADCs and the strips that the bridge sits on to minimize current taken.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So wiring it up as in my second drawing should be correct and ideally I should place a Unity Gain Buffer Amplifier on every analog line?

Comment: Your second drawing has A0 connected to A2 and this seems wrong.

Comment: I see that too but can you provide any suggestions on how it should then be wired? If I remove the connections between A0,A1 and A2, then the analog pins are not connected to R1 anymore....

Comment: Just imagine it as a potentiometer with multiple wipers. You don't need R1 at all - connect the bottom of the ribbon to 0V. Each wiper connects to each analogue input. I believe it's as simple as that. BTW what is the end-to-end resistance of the ribbon?

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. True this could work without R1 but then I will just get a voltage. If I want to measure the resistance on ananalog input, I need to create a voltage divider with a known (fixed) resistor right? 
But how to do this in my situation where, as you said, the potentiometer has multiple wipers?

The resistive strip has 15 kiloOhm/square (My strip is 8mm wide so if I take a 80mm long strip, it will be 150kOhm between the ends).

Comment: PLEASE try and explain in words what you are trying to do. Post those detailed words as an edit within your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help already, I added the details as well to the original post. All help is welcome if you have an idea of how to wire this up for multiple wipers using a known (fixed) resistor.

Comment: Are you ultimately trying to figure the position of the bridge i.e. the wiper position as a percentage from one end to the other because if you are you don't need to measure resistance or understand resistance.